# Is it necessary to compile the Oracle Stored Procedures manually

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle Database Development. I noticed that handful of stored procedures have red cross mark shown on oracle sql developer tool.

I just want to confirm, whether we need to compile all the stored procedures every time we make changes on table schema or view etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, every time when a session try to call a procedure, it first try to recompile it. However, it may take long time to execute or it may even fail.